# How to merge two large Pandas dataframes based on their ID - by reading the biggest file through chunks?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have two CSV files, df1_50GB.csv and df2_1GB.csv. I would like to merge the data frames based on the matched ID value. 
here is what I did so far

```
f50GB =  "df1_50GB.csv"
f1GGB =  "df1_1GGB.csv"
result_file =  "output.csv"

tmp50GB = pd.read_csv(f50GB, nrows=3)
tmp1GB = pd.read_csv(f1GGB, nrows=3)

# creating an empty bucket to save result
df_result = pd.DataFrame(columns=(tmp50GB.columns.append(tmp1GB.columns)).unique())
df_result.to_csv(result_file, index_label=False)
tmp1GB = pd.read_csv(f1GGB)
# Save (append) data which the ID of f1GB  mached with f50GB i.e (x)  #
def save_merged_csv(x):
    df = pd.merge(x, tmp1GB, on='ID', how='left')
    df.to_csv(result_file, mode="a", header=False, index=False)


# create the iterator
csv_reader = pd.read_csv(
    f50GB,
    iterator=True,
    chunksize=100000)

[save_merged_csv(r) for r in csv_reader]
```

But I keep getting errors 'TypeError: Can only merge Series or DataFrame objects, a  was passed'
[UPDATE] The error is now fixed. Thanks to @Michael Gardner. But I am not sure if the logic is correct. The file size of the result is too big. It is also very slow. So,
 I will leave it here if there is room to improve.

Comment: In your `save_merged` func it looks like you need to replace `f1GGB` with `tmp1GB`

Comment: I don't think so, logically the iterator should work on the biggest file (f50GB). Replacing it is not working neither.

Comment: In your code `f1GGB` is the string `"df1_1GGB.csv"` and you are trying to merge it with the chunks of `f50GB`.  That is why you are getting that specific error message.

Comment: Got it. I should have read the f1GB first on memory. Thanks. The code is updated and will leave the question with the working code. As there is room to improve its performance. currently it is performance is quite slow.